# Print n levels of callstack?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

Using C++ with Visual Studio, I was wondering if there's an API that will print the callstack for me.  Preferably, I'd like to print a callstack 5 levels deep.  Does windows provide a simple API to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a number of ways to do this.

See [How to Log Stack Frames with Windows x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590160/how-to-log-stack-frames-with-windows-x64)

In my opinion, the simplest and as well the most reliable way is the Win32 API function:

```
USHORT WINAPI CaptureStackBackTrace(
     __in       ULONG FramesToSkip,
     __in       ULONG FramesToCapture,
     __out      PVOID *BackTrace,
     __out_opt  PULONG BackTraceHash
);
```

This FramesToCapture parameter, determines the maximum call stack depth returned.

Comment: This does not generate any symbolic information.  What use is a bunch of pointer values?

Comment: C/C++ Programs never contain symbolic information by default. See here for ways to add symbols to a stack dump: http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/post-mortem-debugging-revisited/227900186

Answer (score 10):

It looks like Microsoft's DbgHelp library can do what you want. Consult the StackWalk64 function's documentation on MSDN for more information. Also, [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Stackwalk and Stackwalk64 API of the DbgHelp API.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get that out of their debugger API ([dbghelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309(VS.85).aspx)).