# Print callstack at runtime (XCode)

Tags: xcode, runtime, logging, callstack

Is it possible?

I have found solution for Visual Studio [Print n levels of callstack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341796/print-n-levels-of-callstack)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To print a backtrace at runtime programmatically, you can use this function:

```
#import <execinfo.h>

void PrintBacktrace ( void )
{
    void *callstack[128];
    int frameCount = backtrace(callstack, 128);
    char **frameStrings = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frameCount);

    if ( frameStrings != NULL ) {
        // Start with frame 1 because frame 0 is PrintBacktrace()
        for ( int i = 1; i < frameCount; i++ ) {
            printf("%s\n", frameStrings[i]);
        }
        free(frameStrings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `bt` (or `backtrace` command in gdb console). Here's [more info](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/gdb_8.html#SEC44) on command usage.

To print a number of top levels of call stacks you can use `bt n`