# How can I get callstack from C++ application using C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, callstack, dbghelp

I have C#/VB.NET application which tests other application written in C++. If C++ application doesn't respond, I want to get callstack from it. I found various examples written in C++ (e.g. dbghelp.dll [CaptureStackBackTrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341796/print-n-levels-of-callstack/1342186#1342186) or [Walking the callstack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack)), but I found nothing in written C#. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is VB.NET implementation from my team member:

1. Download [ADPlus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and add it into project. The ADPlus is included in [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. Call it with following code:

   ```
   Public Shared Sub DumpCallStack(processID As Integer, outputFolder As String)

       Const serverSymbolPath As String = "http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols"
       Const localSymbolFolder As String = "c:\temp\localSymbols"
       Dim symbolFolderPath As String = String.Format("SRV*{0}* {1}", serverSymbolPath, localSymbolFolder)

       Directory.CreateDirectory(localSymbolFolder)
       Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder)

       Dim arguments As String = String.Format("/c Cscript //nologo ""{0}"" -quiet -quick -NoTlist -p {1} -dbg ""{2}"" -yp ""{3}"" -o ""{4}""",
                               "c:\Adplus\x64\adplus.vbs",
                               processID,
                               "CDB.exe",
                               symbolFolderPath,
                               outputFolder)

       Dim pro As Process = New Process()
       pro.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
       pro.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments
       pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
       pro.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables("_NT_SYMBOL_PATH") = symbolFolderPath

       pro.Start()

       'wait up to 1 minute for the cmd.exe to exit
       pro.WaitForExit(60000)

       'Wait up to 1 minute for the windgb.exe to exit
       WaitForProcessExit("cdb", 60000)
   End Sub

   Private Shared Sub WaitForProcessExit(processName As String, milliseconds As Integer)
       Dim pros As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)
       If pros Is Nothing Then Return

       For Each pro As Process In pros
           pro.WaitForExit(milliseconds)
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

This call creates directory with few files. One of them contains callstacks from target application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options I can think of, but none are using c#.

1. Use adplus or procdump to create a dump of the process.
2. Use the task manager and right click to create a dump of the process.  Be careful about whether the process is 32 bit or 64 bit, you need to take a dump with the same bitness task manager.

Then look at the dump either using windbg or visual studio.

You can automate having adplus or procdump take the dump in c# by calling either of them with a command line parameter.  That still doesn't get you the callstack but you may need to look at multiple callstacks if you have a deadlock involving multiple threads.

You can also look at this link - but it suggests you need to either write a debugger or find some library that does.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90770a1c-7f83-4f81-864f-e64f3e17d02b/get-or-dispaly-call-stack-of-another-process-or-exe-file-in-my-apllication-in-c?forum=netfxbcl

Another option is to use the "Walking the callstack" example in c++.  You can either make an executable that takes in a process id and possibly a filename as command line arguments (could use a guid) and then wait for that file to be written (not fun - but doable).  Or you can try work with managed c++ and wrap the calls to the unmanaged stuff (might be even less fun, but probably more "correct").

Comment: Thanks. But like you said... the dump file is still far from callstack. I cannot get callstack from running process dump even with my VS2012. I prefer something in text form.

Comment: I added a few more options, but whatever you end up doing, it is going to be some work.