# How can I get a stack trace from a core dump generated via Windows MiniDump calls?

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw, coredump

I have an exe compiled with mingw but core dumps generated via the windows MiniDump functions. If I open the core dump in WinDbg, get copy the call stack addresses to a text file, and then run it through addr2line it works. Surely, however, there must be a better way. Is there another debugger which can parse the debug information produced by gcc and the minidump files?

Comment: Usually if you open the dump file in windbg or the visual studio debugger it will load the symbols automatically if they are available and give you a call stack.  Do you have the executable and PDB files for the build the dump was generated with?  A good way to always have them available is to store them using the symbol server.

Comment: @RetiredNinja As I said, the executable was build win mingw-gcc, therefore there is no PDB file.

Comment: http://blog.morlad.at/blah/mingw_postmortem

Answer (score 1):

There's several tools you can use (Visual Studio, WinDbg, DebugDiag) to extract callstacks and even diagnosis from a minidump. I've written a short "how-to" guide to doing so, [which you can find here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394299/434413).

If you're seeing only addresses and not actual function call names and locations, it's most likely that either [your symbol path is not set up correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx) for the tool you're using, or that the .pdb files from your application are missing (and/or you haven't set up a symbol server).

Comment: MinGW toolchain is basically the Linux toolchain (gcc, gdb) ported to Windows, so they don't produce the Microsoft debug symbols. The question was, how to read the Linux symbols from the Windows dump files.