# How to trace the call stack under x64 Windows?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assembly, 64-bit

Under x64 Windows, the return address is not stored in `rbp`; then, how to trace the call stack?

Another related question:

Since the first four arguments are passed via `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8`, and `r9`, how should I retrieve them through the stack trace? (**Especially compiled with optimization.**)

Comment: Which OS? x64 calling conventions differ between Windows and other OSs.

Comment: @Michael, x64 Windows. Especially compiled with optimization.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew5tede7.aspx) and [this](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/09/27/windows-x64-abi-stack-frames/) might be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Windows function `CaptureStackBackTrace`. See [How to Log Stack Frames with Windows x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590160/how-to-log-stack-frames-with-windows-x64) for additional information and code reference.