# find memory allocated between time A and time B which remains unfreed at time C

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2019

I know that Visual Studio allows you to compare memory between two time snapshots in order to find leaks, using the debugger-integrated [Memory Usage diagnostic tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019). However is there a way to filter out of the diff any memory that was allocated after another time point (B) between start time (A) and end time (C) ?

> Time A = start caring about memory that gets allocated
>
> Time B = stop caring
>
> Time C = all memory that was allocated between Time A and Time B should now be freed; if not, let's see the callstack that allocated each chunk

This does not necessarily need to be done using Visual Studio interactive diagnostics tool if is there for example a way to do this using [_CrtMemCheckpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtmemcheckpoint?view=msvc-170) instead or another way.

Although I have tagged this as a Visual Studio 2019 question, I will accept any solution that uses freely available Microsoft tools such as WinDbg or Free Open Source tools such as VLD (Visual Leak Detector) to achieve the same result.

Comment: Probably, stupid question... Do you mean - only dynamic memory allocation (explicitly by "new") or including all other allocation?

Comment: @LunchBasketball all heap allocated memory. so there is a "new" somewhere but it may be hidden inside standard library code rather than "explicit."

Comment: Overloading new/delete is trivial. Having a global flag that start/stops the trace is trivial. The complex part getting a hashtable with stack traces and addresses of allocation. I'll look if there's a library somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the target platform is Windows since VS2019 is mentioned, I've found a tool similar to what you are looking for.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11221/Easy-Detection-of-Memory-Leaks

It is pretty old but still compiles.

Code from MemoryHooks can be used for new/delete override implementation. (`void* operator new  (std::size_t count ); and void operator delete  (void* ptr);`)

Comment: The single process limitation is a slight annoyance, but this should still be useful. And it does meet all my criteria set for the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the comments suggest that it doesn't work for 64 bit Windows and it links to a fork which presumably fixes that. https://sourceforge.net/projects/diagnostic/
(looks a bit shady t.b.h. since the fork requires some "password" and acknowledgement of the author, but no mention of the original author)

Comment: The main thing should be ripped out of it - map implementation that does not use STL - stack capture is described in many places, e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590160/how-to-log-stack-frames-with-windows-x64